# Change the __str__ function of frozenset (or any other native type)

Tags: python, printing, frozenset

I am working with frozensets.

When I do `print(my_frozenset)` the output is something like  "frozenset({1, 2, 3})".

However I have many nested frozensets and I find this print very long and hard to read.

I want to modify it so that `print(my_frozenset)` outputs, for example, "fs{1,2,3}" or something different.

Comment: What stops you from subclassing `frozenset`? What issues did you face in case you tried?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75186671/8285840 for how to apporach altering `__str__` for frozensets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to modify the native code directly.

You can define new function to print `frozenset` or new class inherit `frozenset`.

If you have to replace the built-in `frozenset`, you can try like this

```
import builtins


class _frozenset(frozenset):
    def __str__(self):
        return "custom..."


builtins.frozenset = _frozenset

print(frozenset([1, 2, 3]))
```

But this may cause unexpected errors