# Improve print readability of nested Frozenset

Tags: python, printing, format, frozenset

The output of the code example below has terrible readability. The data I'd like to analyse is hidden within numerous `frozenset({})` prints.

```py
A = frozenset(["A1", "A2"])
B = frozenset(["B1", "B2"])
C = frozenset(["C1", "C2"])

foo = {A, B, C}

print(foo)
# {frozenset({'B1', 'B2'}), frozenset({'C1', 'C2'}), frozenset({'A1', 'A2'})}

print(*foo)
# frozenset({'B1', 'B2'}) frozenset({'C1', 'C2'}) frozenset({'A1', 'A2'})
```

Is there an easy way to neglect the printouts of the `data collection type`? I'm only interested in the grouping of the entries.

A more readable output would be:

```
({'B1', 'B2'}, {'C1', 'C2'}, {'A1', 'A2'})
```

**TLD**
I stumbled upon this issue when trying to find to optimal way to group a large number of items in pairs. The grouping had to comply to a lot of boundary conditions and I need a quick check if the solution found makes sense.

```py
items = {'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', 'A1', 'A2'}
pairs = get_best_grouping(items) # Outputs a set containing frozensets
print(pairs)
```

[Change the **str** function of frozenset (or any other native type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434532/change-the-str-function-of-frozenset-or-any-other-native-type) is a related question, but seems like a big intervention for this problem.

Comment: Can you write down what string format you would expect `print` to result in? I don't see how the __str__ function you mention (congrats for doing your homework btw) is not excately what you are after.

Comment: @MatthiasArras I've edited my question to address your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, writing your own `__str__` or `__repr__` function would be the propper way to go, if that sounds too much hassle, how about you modify the string after the fact?

`print(str(frozenset({1,2,3})).replace('frozenset',''))`

> ({1, 2, 3})

Assuming of course your set does not contain the word "frozenset".

But it is really not much more effort to make a new `_frozenset` class follwing the same logic as above (note the `1` in replace to make sure that we only replace the first occurence of the str '_frozenset'.):

```py
class _frozenset(frozenset):
    def __repr__(self):
        return (frozenset.__repr__(self)).replace('_frozenset','',1)

print(_frozenset([1, 2, '_frozenset']))
```

> ({1, 2, '_frozenset'})

Imho, key is here to simply reuse the definition of `__repr__` of the builtin `frozenset` so we don't have to worry too much about the logic behind how to represent an iterable. Against first intuition, `frozenset.__repr__()` seems to (I have not looked into it) inspect the name of the `class` it is in and prepend that so it is not `'frozenset'` but `'_frozenset'` one needs to replace.